# Draw on a Canvas Using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, canvas

I'm using selenium with java (latest for both). Trying to draw on a small canvas area inside a modal in our webapp. The library we used for our canvas was 'signature pad js'. I have confirmed it is not inside an iframe or anything tricky that could be the problem (it's just a regular div.modal-body with a div.signature-input canvas element).

But it is not doing anything. Have looked at many posts here on stackoverflow and most of them seem pretty identical with few variations to try (I've been trying them all).

Here's the latest code I tried:
// Draw a signature of some sort

WebElement element = driver.findElement(Using.locator(SIGNATURE_AREA)); // canvas element

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(10, 50).
      moveByOffset(50,10).
      moveByOffset(-10,-50).
      moveByOffset(-50,-10).release().perform();

I've tried all sorts of offsets, and such to no avail.
If anyone has experience with this, would really love a hand.

Answer (score 5):

I think your issue is in the code , I've done this with ruby and it worked fine.. Code in Ruby below (worked in FireFox)

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/canvas").click
  element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/canvas");
  driver.action.move_to(element).perform
  driver.action.click_and_hold(element).perform
  driver.action.move_by(150, 50).click.perform
  driver.action.move_to(element).perform
  driver.action.click_and_hold(element).perform
  driver.action.move_by(100, 50).click.perform
  driver.action.move_to(element).perform
  driver.action.click_and_hold(element).perform
  driver.action.move_by(300, 10).click.perform
sleep (5)
```

So I have tried same thing using Java for you , and its working fine , Its drawing two lines as expected. The trick is that moveby should not be followed with a click otherwise it will loose focus. Below code is working fine in java and chrome . I used https://sketchtoy.com/ to draw on canvas

```
public class BrowserTesting {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
        //WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\pathtyourchrome\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        //disable automation info bar
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://sketchtoy.com/");

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='sketch-canvas-container']/canvas"));//canvas element
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
        builder.clickAndHold(element).perform();
        builder.moveByOffset(150, 50).perform();
        builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
        builder.clickAndHold(element).perform();
        builder.moveByOffset(100, 50).perform();
        builder.moveToElement(element).perform();




        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //driver.quit();

    }

}
```

See this screen shot for the drawing: [image: Sketch Drawing]

Let me know if this worked!

Comment: Issue in which code sorry? MY code or the application's code?

Comment: your code, you need to move to element the click and hold then move by

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, I've tried many combinations of actions, none of them ever made even a single dot on the canvas.

Comment: e.g. Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(element).clickAndHold(element).moveByOffset(1, 1).moveByOffset(2, 2).release().build().perform();

Comment: I'll give it a go.

Comment: Didn't work for me (no effect on canvas). At this point I'm considering giving up. I have managed to make it put a single dot on the canvas just using element.click(); which is probably enough for my testing efforts.

Comment: can you share the application url or its a private application?

Comment: It's a private application, so I can't really divulge logins unfortunately.